# Booting Ubuntu but just says /dev/mmcblk0p2: clean,

Tags: boot, dual-boot, software-installation, chromebook

I have seen a lot of question like this one on here but what I have not gotten is the replies from the people who have asked about whether the answer has worked or not basically tried to boot ubuntu and it went well it worked and I installed it something somewhere went wrong and now when I try to boot it says clean not telling me to clean but just clean more things too I just remember that one ill try to find it an write it in the title, anyways I looked at an answer that said troubleshoot so I did it ctrl-alt-1-7 but 1-6 just tells me to log in and runs a whole scrip than stops unexpectedly and 7 is where it says /dev/mmcblk0p2: clean,. I hope this was not too long and I hope that someone can answer my question (edited) - it worked earlier (yesterday) but I trashed the file and it renamed the file trash 1000 but kept the files so I renamed it ubuntu than tried to restart it up on my Chromebook and it still has old entries from it and I don't know how to delete those to start ALL over – Jamir just now (edit) ubuntu 20.04, not fresh just happened.

Comment: Does the computer boot correctly from a Ubuntu-USB Live Stick? What Ubuntu version do you use? Is this a fresh installation or did it work some time and just broke recently?. Please click the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1282154/edit) link and add the information.

Comment: it worked earlier (yesterday) but I trashed the file and it renamed the file trash 1000 but kept the files so I renamed it ubuntu than tried to restart it up on my Chromebook and it still has old entries from it and I don't know how to delete those to start ALL over

Comment: and i dont mid im sorry vote to close it

Comment: What file did you "trash" and how did you do it? Is reinstalling Ubuntu a option?

Comment: @MadMike on windows i trashed the bootable folder of ubuntu than instead of trashing or deleting i guess since i did not empty trash it just said trash so i renamed t back to ubuntu os